# Trained a model using ssd_inception_v2_coco, what do i do next?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I followed a tutorial about detecting objects using deep learning here: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

At some point, after training up to 4082 steps, i stopped the training using CTRL+C.

Now i have bunch of files under my training directory, which looks like this:

[list of files in the training directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz7J1.png)

The question is, how do i proceed now? what to do next? the tutorial doesn't teach you how to use the training data, how to even test it if its recognizing correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you obtained are checkpoints. What you want to do now is to restore your model from the checkpoints. Indications from [CV tricks](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  model = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
  model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

After, you can evaluate your model on your [test set](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough):

```
test_accuracy = tfe.metrics.Accuracy()

for (x, y) in test_dataset:
  logits = model(x)
  prediction = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
  test_accuracy(prediction, y)

print("Test set accuracy: {:.3%}".format(test_accuracy.result()))
```